# C: Define own function instead of callback in SQLite

Tags: c, sqlite

As shown from the SQLite site, sqlite3_exec calls `callback` at every record returned for some action:

```
int sqlite3_exec(
sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
```

);

Is it possible to invoke another self defined function to do a different set of actions on every record instead of editing the `callback` function?

For example, `sqlite3_exec(db, sql, display, 0, &zErrMsg);`, where `display` is a function to display all records in the terminal.

EDIT: I thought about overloading the function, but I don't think C supports overloading.

Comment: C does not support overloading, but it does allow for repeated function arguments, (using the ellipsis, `...`, operator).  However, have you considered using the callback function to simply call another function that would, as you suggest, display all records in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use another function, like this:

```
sqlite3_exec(db, sql, display, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

The name "callback" is just the name of the parameter as used internally by the `sqlite3_exec` function; your own functions can be named whatever you like.